# Method to operate on each row of data.table without using apply function

Tags: r, data.table

I wrote a simple function below:

`mcs <- function(v) { ifelse(sum((diff(sort(v)) > 6) > 0), NA, sd(v)) }`

It is supposed to take a vector, sort it and then check if there is difference greater than 6 in each successive difference. It returns NA if there is a difference greater than 6 and the standard deviation if there is not.

I would like to apply this function across all rows of a data table (choosing only certain columns) and then append the return value for each row as a new column entry to the data table.

For example, given a data table like so

```
> dat <- data.table(A=c(1,2,3,4,5), B=c(2,3,4,10,6), C=c(3,4,10,6,8),   
D=c(3,3,3,3,3))  
> dat  
   A  B  C D  
1: 1  2  3 3  
2: 2  3  4 3  
3: 3  4 10 3  
4: 4 10  6 3  
5: 5  6  8 3
```

I would like to generate the output below. (I applied function on column 2, 3, and 4 of each row.)

```
> dat
   A  B  C D        sd
1: 1  2  3 3 0.5773503
2: 2  3  4 3 0.5773503
3: 3  4 10 3 3.7859389
4: 4 10  6 3 3.5118846
5: 5  6  8 3 2.5166115
```

I learned that by row operation can be done with data tables using the following method:

```
> dat[, sd:=apply(.SD, 1, mcs), .SDcols=(c(2,3,4))]
```

And this method works except that it is too slow. I have to perform this operation on several large data tables and I wrote a script to do so. However, it only works for smaller data tables. For the tables with ~300,000 rows it finishes in a few seconds, but when I try to do so with a table that has ~800 million rows, my program doesn't finish. I've tried waiting for two hours and I think R breaks or something because the console just freezes. I've tried running the script several times and it always finishes the first few smaller tables correctly (I had the program write the table to a file to check) but when it reaches the large data table, it never finishes. I am running this on a computing cluster so I definitely don't think this is a hardware limitation. Probably poor code.

I am assuming the bottleneck is the looping done in apply, but I don't how to make it faster. I am pretty new to R so I am not sure how to optimize my code. I've seen a lot of posts around the Internet about vectorizing and I am thinking maybe if I could simultaneously apply my function to every row it would be much faster, but I don't know how to do that. Please help.

**Edit**
Sorry, I made a mistake in copying my `mcs` function. I have updated it.

**Edit 2**
For those interested, I ended up splitting the table in half and operating on each half separately and that worked for me.

Comment: You should double check your `mcs` function because its outputs are different. Applying on the first row `mcs(c(1,2,3,3)` results in `0.9574271` and not in `0.5773503` as you posted.

Comment: I was able to get the computation time down by 25% with the function `mcs2 <- function(...) {ifelse(sum(diff(sort(c(...),method="quick")) > 6), NA, sd(c(...)))}` and calling it as `dat[, sd2:= mapply(mcs2, B, C, D)]`. but almost all of that gain is caused by just using the sorting method "quick", tested on 100.000 rows and 5 columns. I hope someone else comes up with a faster alternative though, curious to see other solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really need speed, as always it's best to move to C++ using Rcpp, which gives us a solution that's over 100x faster.

#### Data

I did make some different example data to test this on that had 1000 rows instead of 5:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.table(A = rnorm(1e3, sd=4), B = rnorm(1e3, sd=4), C = rnorm(1e3, sd=4),
                  D = rnorm(1e3, sd=4), E = rnorm(1e3, sd=4))
```

#### Solution

I used the following C++ code to do the same thing as your function, but now the looping is done in C++ instead of R through apply which saves considerable time:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector mcs2(DataFrame x) {
    int n = x.nrows();
    int m = x.size();
    NumericMatrix mat(n, m);
    for ( int j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
        mat(_, j) = NumericVector(x[j]);
    }
    NumericVector result(n);
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        NumericVector tmp = mat(i, _);
        std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
        bool do_sd = true;
        for ( int j = 1; j < m; ++j ) {
            if ( tmp[j] - tmp[j-1] > 6.0 ) {
                result[i] = NA_REAL;
                do_sd = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( do_sd ) {
            result[i] = sd(tmp);
        }
        do_sd = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

We can make sure it's returning the same values:

```
all.equal(apply(dat[, 2:4], 1, mcs1), mcs2(dat[,2:4]))

[1] TRUE
```

Now let's benchmark:

```
benchmark(mcs1 = dat[, sd:=apply(.SD, 1, mcs1), .SDcols=(c(2,3,4))],
          mcs2 = dat[, sd:=mcs2(.SD), .SDcols=(c(2,3,4))],
          order = 'relative',
          columns = c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative', 'user.self'))


  test elapsed relative user.self
2 mcs2    0.19    1.000     0.183
1 mcs1   21.34  112.316    20.044
```

#### How to compile this code

As an introduction to using C++ code through Rcpp, I'd suggest [this chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-intro) of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R. If you intend on doing anything further with Rcpp I'd strongly recommend you also read the official documentation and vignettes, but Wickham's book is probably a little more beginner friendly to use as a starting point. For your purposes, you just need to get Rcpp up and running so that you can compile the code above.

For this code to work for you, you'll need the Rcpp package if you don't already have it. You can get the package by running

```
install.packages(Rcpp)
```

from R. Note you'll also need a compiler; if you're on a Debian-based Linux system such as Ubuntu you can run

```
sudo apt install r-base-dev
```

from the terminal. If you are on Mac or Windows, check [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486498) for some instructions on getting this set up, or in the Wickham chapter linked above.

Once you have Rcpp installed, save the C++ code above into a file. Let's say for our example the file is named "SOanswer.cpp". Then you can make its `mcs2()` function available from R by putting the following two lines in your R script:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("SOanswer.cpp") # assuming the file is in your working directory
```

That's it! Now your R script can call `mcs2()` and run much faster. If you want to learn more about Rcpp, beside the Wickham chapter above, I'd check out the reference manual and the vignettes available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html), [this page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-RStudio) from RStudio (which also has tons of links, some of which are linked to here), and you can also find some really useful stuff looking around the [Rcpp gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/).

Comment: `mcs` in the OP uses `sum(diff(sort(v)) > 6)` and not `sum(diff(sort(v))) > 6`. Also, in `all.equal`, the "sd" column of "dat" gets overwritten the second time (with `mcs3`) and, as a result, the same object is passed twice to `all.equal`.

Comment: Are you going to write a RCPP variant  that checks if sny of the consequent differences is larger than 6 too? Would be curious for its performance. Also, I used mapply to call the function msc2, instead of using apply with .SD. That should increase performance a bit.

Comment: @Florian -- yeah, was working on it when you commented; it's added now

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not familiar with using C++ in R. Do I just write C++ code directly in the same script as R code, or do I need to make a separate C++ file?

Comment: @RegisteredUser I'll edit the answer to include some instructions on that

Comment: @RegisteredUser Some explanation on how to get the C++ function compiled and available for your R script are now added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The code works for the smaller tables, but after running on the large table for a few hours, I get an arror:  `*** caught segfault ***` `'address 0x7f79df4e5048, cause 'memory not mapped'` Did the program run out of memory?

Comment: @RegisteredUser I will look into this later today